# Bulma: Using Mixins with Variables

Tags: sass, bulma

I am using the mixins in Bulma for screen size (+mobile and +desktop) which work well in some circumstances.

```
.front-page
  +desktop
    padding-right: 120px!important

  +tablet
    padding-right: 60px!important

  p
    +mobile
      font-size: 1.1rem
      padding-bottom: 10px      
      line-height: 1.3

    +tablet
      font-size: 1.3rem
      padding-bottom: 10px      
      line-height: 1.3
```

However, I am trying to use the following which does NOT work. What am I doing wrong please?

```
.Site-content
  flex: 1
  +mobile
    padding-top: 100px!important

  +desktop
    padding-top: 0px!important
```